# Eclipse “Duplicate Location” while install new Sequoyah plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, installation

When I am trying to install [Sequoyah](http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/) in Eclipse from **Help -> Install New Software** , either through online installation or using downloaded local site archive it gives error **Duplicate Location**.

Or even first time when I select the downloaded archived file it does not show the files rather check box with **There are no categorized items**

please help. I even tried to delete Eclipse and unpack and did all this again but same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this  error means that the location you are trying to add exists already. Try to search sequoyah in the "type filter text" box, and uncheck the "Group items by category" checkbox

Comment: I type "sequoyah" or http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/ it does not show any thing.

Comment: did you try to add http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/ in the location field?

Comment: yes, first time it Showed "There are no categorized items" and when I tried it again it is showing duplicate location with OK button disabled. Then i tried with downloaded archived file but no success

Comment: ok.. if you click on the arrow next to the add button you should find the sequoah location. Select it and un check the "Group items by category" checkbox

Comment: just uncheck the "Group items by category"

Answer (score 6):

It didn't show up for me in "Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites", but I was able to get it work. I could add it from there and I didn't get the error message. Then, I had to click "Disable", "Reload", "Enable", "Reload", or else it would disappear after closing the window. I'm not sure if all those clicks were strictly necessary, but it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I run into this fairly often when installing new versions of eclipse and not being able to use update sites that I added in the old version.

Try this:

- Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites    (or control-3 and type "sites")
- look at the list of disabled sites (filter text is helpful to search them) and see if the one you want to use is listed as disabled

  - enabling it will make it show up in the Install New Software drop down

Some more info here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/20746/  and  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238619

Answer (score 1):

Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software sites, Search for your link.
Remove it.

Now try adding again.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software sites, Search for your link. Remove it.
And New ADT Plugin Download from https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.1.0.zip then install this zip file.
How to Install ADT-21.1.0.zip? 
Answer:-Eclipse in Help->Install new Software->Add->Archive in bind this zip file from your drive location.

Answer (score 0):

click "Disable", "Reload", "Enable", "Reload"

It's weird(certainly a bug)...but it worked.